# How to apply 40% blending effect to photos with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I apologize for the awkwardness of English by using the translator.

I'd like to apply photo 2 to photo 1 with a 40% overlay effect.
I succeeded in overlaying it, but it's 100%.
Is there a way to apply 40% of the blending effect?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufYph.jpg)

Below is the code I used.

magick convert -composite -compose overlay 1.png 2.png out.png

here is a psd example file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hE8LHCO5pWOiWvguce463ZVMw9LdV0pv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I was able to access your PSD file and exported it as a PNG and can see what process it uses in terms of the transparency values set and blending mode.

[image]

I separated out the base image, which is as follows.

[image]

So here are 3 variations in Imagemagick 7 that are close to what Photoshop is creating:

```
magick cat.png -alpha off \( +clone -fill yellow -colorize 40% \) -compose overlay -composite cat_yellow1.png
```

[image]

```
magick cat.png -alpha off \( +clone -fill yellow -colorize 100% -channel a -evaluate set 40% +channel \) \( -clone 0 \) -compose overlay -composite cat_yellow2.png
```

[image]

```
magick cat.png -alpha off \( +clone -fill yellow -colorize 100% \) \( -clone 0 \) -define compose:args=40,60 -compose overlay -composite cat_yellow3.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify percentage mix like this:

```
magick 1.png 2.png -define compose:args=40,60 -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

Avoid `magick convert ...` it leads to older, v6 behaviour which is rarely desirable. Also, try to specify input images **before** operators applied to them.

Comment: It still comes out in 100% overlay blending mode...

Comment: Not at a computer to test for a while. Maybe try `-compose blend`

Comment: It still comes out 100%.
I attach the image because I think there was a lack of explanation.
https://i.imgur.com/abrRRji.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Mark is correct. Use -compose blend. You would do the following on Imagemagick 7

```
magick 1.png 2.png -define compose:args=40,60 -compose blend -composite result.png
```

If using Imagemagick 6, then change `magick` to `convert`.

Comment: The result just appears as if the image was overlapped on top of the image.
It seems that the explanation is not enough, so I am attaching an image.
https://i.imgur.com/abrRRji.jpeg

Comment: That image is not sufficient. Please post your two input images and and image of what you expect for the output.

Comment: Please also identify your Imagemagick version and platform/OS

Comment: It seems that I couldn't explain it in the image, so I attached a PSd example file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hE8LHCO5pWOiWvguce463ZVMw9LdV0pv/view?usp=sharing
And my Imagemagick version and platform/OS  is window 10 64bit, ImageMagick-7.1.0-26-Q16-HDRI-x64

Comment: You have made this very difficult to access on your Google account. I need access permission from you to access it. That does not make it very appealing to help you.

Comment: I forgot to update the file Sharing options. I'm sorry.
I updated file Sharing options.
I'm sorry to bother you. TT

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to apply color to an image using ImageMagick. If some particular method isn't giving the results you're looking for, maybe explore some other options. Here are some example commands and the kinds of results we might get...

The input images...

[image]  [image]

---

A simple composite with the "overlay" method...

```
magick 1.png 2.png -compose overlay -composite test_overlay.png
```

[image]

---

A 40/60 composite with the "blend" method...

```
magick 1.png 2.png -compose blend -define compose:args=40,60 -composite test_blend.png
```

[image]

---

Using the "colorize" method to apply the color...

```
magick 1.png 2.png -compose colorize -composite test_colorize.png
```

[image]

---

Composite with the "multiply" compose method...

```
magick 1.png 2.png -compose multiply -composite test_multiply.png
```

[image]

---

Add color to the image using `-tint`...

```
magick 1.png -fill #F5FF00 -tint 100 test_tint.png
```

[image]

---

Comment: What I wanted to ask you is how to apply 40% of the effect you wrote to the photograph..TT

here is a psd example file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hE8LHCO5pWOiWvguce463ZVMw9LdV0pv/view?usp=sharing